# Ruby Boolean assignment operator in a loop

Tags: ruby, loops

Given the following code:

```
File.open('file1.txt', 'r') do |file|
  while line = file.gets
    puts "** " + line.chomp.reverse + " **"
  end
end
```

I am confused to what is the question being asked? This is a simple piece of code I got off my tutorial, that reads a file's lines and puts it out. I do understand most of it, I believe you are assigning a variable `line` to the return value of `file.gets`, and it retrieves the value of those lines, and puts it out.

Where I am having trouble is the initial loop statement: `while line = file gets`

My question is that what kind of question are you asking and how does it break out of the loop?

i.e.:`x=3 x ==3`--> You are asking is X equal to 3, if true will return `true`, if false will return `false`.

Also, are you simultaneously assigning the return value of `file.gets` to the variable `line`, in addition to putting it in the while statement?

Comment: I would prefer `IO.foreach("file1.txt") {  |line| puts "** " + line.chomp.reverse + " **" }`. See [IO::foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach). (This is often written `File.foreach(...`, which works because `File` is a subclass of `IO`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby everything evaluates to truthy or falsey.

There are two falsey things:

- `nil`
- `false`

Everything else is truthy.

The `while` loop checks for truthiness of `line` variable.

Until it is anything but either `nil` or `false` it loops.

In your example the loop will stop when `file.gets` returns `nil`, meaning, there's no next line.

Comment: Ok and truthy and falsy refers to is the data type set by Ruby to true or false?

Comment: @the12 Predicates typically return one of the Boolean values `true` or `false`, but this is not required, as any value other than `false` or `nil` works like `true` when a Boolean value is required. Meaning `while 2` would work, as well as `while true` or `while 'hello world'`

Comment: Ok and just to double check, you are assigning the value of file.gets to the variable line AND putting it in the while statement?

Comment: @the12 yes, assigning operator here takes precedence, so `while foo = 2` actually evaluates to `while 2` which basically means `while true`.

Comment: @the12: assignment operator returns value that was assigned. That's why it is possible to simultaneously assign some variable __and__ test it in a conditional.

Comment: Thank you again @SergioTulentsev :)

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that `while` is using the variable `line` as its condition. `line = file.gets` is assigned before `while` checks the condition. Additionally, `while` knows how to break out of the loop because at EOF `file.gets` returns `nil` which is `false`-y.